# How do I model relative time spend doing different behaviours?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis, linear-model, multivariate-regression

I have a dataset comprising observations of ducks performing different behaviours. Specifically, ducks were observed for 1 minute each, and during each 1 minute observation the amount of time that ducks spent performing different behaviours was recorded. For example, ducks may have been recorded as preening for 20 seconds, defensive for 10 seconds, foraging for 20 seconds, and 10 seconds being vigilant. As an example, my data look like this:

[image: Example of dataset]

I want to model what drives different behaviours (i.e. what determines the relative amount of time spent performing different behaviours). I have several explanatory variables, such as number of other ducks in the vicinity, a site variable indicating which of 3 locations the ducks were observed at, etc.

Normally I would fit something like a GLM, such as the following:

`glm(behaviourDuration ~ ducksInVinicity + Site)`

But in this case my response variable is not just *duration* but 4 different durations, i.e. the *duration of one of four specific behaviours*. I know I can't do 4 separate GLMs because I want to compare the behaviours directly, so fitting a separate model for each wont allow me to do this.

Hence should I be using something like Multivariate Multiple Regression, as seen [here](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/#:%7E:text=Again%20the%20term%20%E2%80%9Cmultivariate%E2%80%9D%20here,predictor%20contributes%20to%20a%20model.&text=The%20results%20are%20titled%20%E2%80%9CType%20II%20MANOVA%20Tests%E2%80%9D.), where I essentially have 4 dependent variables (the duration of each of the 4 different behaviours) included in the same model as the response? If that's the case then my model formulation would look something like:

`glm(cbind(durationPreening, durationDefensive, durationForaging, durationVigilant) ~ ducksInVicinity + Site)`.

Would this method be OK? And would it be OK to use the raw duration values (in seconds) or would it be better to transform the duration values to relative duration (in percentage). For example 20 seconds of preening would become 20/60 = 0.33 to signify that the duck spent 33% of its time preening.

Finally, one other option I considered was just to model *duration* as the response and then include *behaviour* as a predictor variable. I could do this either with the raw duration values or first transform my raw duration values into relative duration (as above), as follows:

`glm(relativeDuration ~ ducksInVinicity + Site + Behaviour)`

Of course if I use this last method, I may need to use an interaction term to determine if there is a significant interaction between Behaviour and ducksInVinicty, i.e. `+ ducksInVinicity:Behaviour`

Any thoughts/advice on what modelling method is best to use would be much appreciated.

Thank you!